# Input Accessory View Swift Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, inputaccessoryview

I have a View Controller, called Chat View Controller, that's organised in Storyboard as follows:
[image: Chat View Controller Storyboard Layout]

This is accessed with a navigation controller. Basically what this View Controller is is a view similar to that of Apple's Messages app. The "View" that you can see outside the Chat View Controller at the bottom is the view that I'm trying to add as an Input Accessory View, and is called messagingView. To add this as an input accessory view, I use this code within the Chat View Controller:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    return messagingView // This is the "View"
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Now when the view loads, the messagingView is added to the view, but it's height is 568px! There are no constraints on the width/height of the messagingView and this is added automatically as a constraint called "_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint". I have tried using my messagingView within Apple's own KeyboardAccessory sample code and it works perfectly (that is written in Objective C). I have tried recreating their sample code in Swift and it gives exactly the same problem as I'm having! This must be a Swift bug?! Or am I forgetting to do something??

Thank you

Comment: did you try putting constraints on the height in the storyboard?

Comment: @Steve Yes I did try that, but it causes a "constraints conflict" and removes my constraint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a bug in Swift. Found that the simplest way is to edit the `_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint` constant in `updateViewConstraints()`, so that it reloads the height of the inputAccessoryView before the view appears

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    let constraint:NSLayoutConstraint = (tableView.inputAccessoryView!.constraints() as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0) as NSLayoutConstraint
    constraint.constant = 52
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```